# Node/Express session value insert

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm currently working on a project using Node/Express/MongoDB. I'm using Mongoose to create my schema's and interface with DB. I'm using "express-sessions" module and have a session value set. Specifically, "req.session.user" which equals the username when logged in.

My question here, is how do I go about inserting the session value into mongodb? I have my model defined properly.

doc_type.model.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var TypesSchema = new Schema({
  type_id: {
    type: String,
    uppercase: true,
    required: true
  },
  type_description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  created_by: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  creation_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('document_types', TypesSchema);
```

admin.js with routes defined.

```
adminRouter.route('/doc_types')

.get((req, res) => {
  Type.find({}, (err, types) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err)
      res.json(err)
    }
    else if (!req.session.user || !req.session.badge) {
      res.redirect('/login');
    }
    else if (req.session.user || req.session.badge) {
      res.render('doc_types', { pageTitle: 'Document Types', types: types, currentUser: req.session.user })

    }
  })
})

.post((req, res) => {
  var type = new Type();

  type.type_id = req.body.input_type_id;
  type.type_description = req.body.input_type_description;
  type.created_by = req.session.user;

  type.save((err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err)
      res.json(err)
    }
    else {
      res.json("Success!");
    }
  })
});
```

If you look under the .post method, you'll notice the line "type.created_by = req.session.user;". I then save my data into my db via schema. Upon doing so, my session value isn't passed into mongoose scheme. It's empty. However, when I console.log the req.session value, it displays fine there.

Can someone clarify my issue here? I'm stumped. It's probably something stupid I've overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, it was something stupid. :) I was using postman to "POST" my data to the page. Postman has no idea what the session value was, therefore, no data sent to the mongoose document id. The session was only stored on the server/browser side. Lesson learned, haha.